# how to count zero after the last non-zero digit in C

Tags: c

I need to count the number of zeroes after the last none-zero digit of a number

Example input: 20400

Example output: 2

This is my code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int lastZero(int n);
int main()
{
    int number,lastZeroDigit;
    int i;
    scanf("%d",&number);
    lastZeroDigit = lastZero(number);
    
    for(i=number-1 ; i>1 ; i--)
        lastZeroDigit = lastZero(lastZeroDigit * i);
        
    printf(" %d \n",lastZeroDigit);
}

int lastZero(int n) 
{
    if(n%10 != 0)
        return n%10;
    
    else
        return lastZero(n/10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> > how to count zero after the last non-zero digit in C

Why are you iterating from `number - 1` to `>1` and checking the last zero in `lastZeroDigit * i` number? If you just want to count the number of zero's in a number after last non-zero digit then simply check the result of `number % 10` and if result is `0` then increase a counter and do `number = number / 10` and check again otherwise stop. A special care need to be taken for `0` input, which is - if the input is `0` no need to check because there is no non zero digit in the input number. You can do:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int number;
    unsigned int count = 0;

    printf ("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf ("%d", &number);
    
    while (number && (number % 10 == 0)) {
        ++count;
        number = number / 10;
    }
        
    printf ("Zero's after last non zero digit in number %d are : %u \n", number, count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is enough to check once that number is not 0, no need to check it each iteration.